# Will vaccinating babies weeks after birth reduce the spread of measles?

Tags: vaccination

I understand that young babies (around 0-6 months old) have antibodies passed from their mothers, which is why they are vaccinated with MMR at 6-12 months old in New Zealand. However, there are still many cases where babies 0-6 months old are getting infected with measles.

Why can't we give babies the MMR vaccine weeks after birth, and still give them a second dose 6-12 months after birth? Babies who are 0-6 months old are usually vaccinated if they are going to countries with high-risk of contracting measles - why can't we "play it safe" and vaccinate all babies during this time period? Will vaccinating them this early help reduce the spread of measles?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?